# setup and teardown don't reset array properties in controllers

Tags: ember.js

I prepared a [short ember-cli project](https://github.com/pogopaule/failing-toggle-test/) that shows a behaviour in Ember.js tests, I don't undestand.

There is a [simple controller](https://github.com/pogopaule/failing-toggle-test/blob/master/app/controllers/index.js#L4-L8)

```
...
list: [],

actions: {
  add: function() {
   this.get('list').pushObject('a');
  }
}
...
```

a [template](https://github.com/pogopaule/failing-toggle-test/blob/master/app/templates/index.hbs)

```
<button id="btn" {{action 'add'}}>add a</button>
<span id="list">
{{#each item in list}}
  {{item}}
{{/each}}
</span>
```

and [two tests](https://github.com/pogopaule/failing-toggle-test/blob/master/tests/unit/toggle-test.js#L15-L40)

```
...
test('test 1', function() {
  expect(1);

  visit('/');
  click('#btn');

  andThen(function() {
    ok(true);
  });
});

test('test 2', function() {
  expect(1);

  visit('/');
  click('#btn');

  andThen(function() {
    equal(find('#list').text().trim(), 'a');
  });
});
...
```

Run the tests (`http://localhost:4200/tests`) multiple times. You will notice that 'test 2' fails every second time. The reason for that is, that the state set by 'test 1' does not get cleaned up by either the setup or the teardown phase. So there are two A's in `list`  on the `IndexController` in 'test 2'. The first one added by 'test 1' and the second one by 'test 2'. I would expect that any state on a controller set by a test is gone after the teardown and the next setup phase...

My questions are: Why does this happen, why does state from 'test 1' leak into 'test 2'? Is [this](https://github.com/pogopaule/failing-toggle-test/blob/master/app/controllers/index.js#L8) the wrong way to handle arrays in ember? Is this a bug in ember?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you're giving the same array to all instances of your controller. It's just a quirk of how Javascript objects work and how Ember creates instances of classes. You can fix it by giving each instance its own array object. You do that by explicitly setting the value during initialization.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    list: null,

    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('list', []);
    }
});
```

Now each instance of your controller will get a brand new array.

Comment: so in Java-lingo `list: []` is a bit like saying `static List list = new ArrayList()`?

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair analogy. Ember has its own concept of static properties though, so try not to get the two confused.